# how can I make disabled required fields invalidate a reactive form

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, angular-reactive-forms

I have a simple reactive form like this :

```
  this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        firstInput: '',
        secondInput: [{value:'', disabled: true}, Validators.required],
  });
```

I want `secondInput` to be initially disabled so that the user is forced to fill out `firstInput` first. Then when my component detects that `firtInput` was provided, I activate `secondInput` like this

```
 this.myForm.controls.secondInput.enable();
```

But with the code above, when the user types inside `firstInput`, myForm is valid since the rule of secondInput that should invalidate it is disabled...

How can I achieve the expected behavior ? That is have a `secondInput` disabled in the template, while it's validator stays active.

Comment: How are you enabling `secondInput` when the user fills out `firstInput`?

Comment: this.myForm.controls.secondInput.enable();

Comment: Sure, but at what point do you call this?

Comment: this.myForm.controls.firstInput.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
            // if firstInput is supplied activate secondInput
        })

Comment: You can try running [`this.myForm.updateValueAndValidity()`](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#updateValueAndValidity) although I think this would be run after calling `.enable`

Comment: What is the problem, I mean, if field is disabled, user cannot type in the field, so form would never be valid if you want to field to be required even if it's disabled. This I gather from comment: `That is have a secondInput disabled in the template, while it's validator stays active.`